# How Stack Overflow occur if we use linked list for stack implementation?

Tags: stack, structure, overflow

I am new to stacks. As we know, if there is not enough space in stack and we want to push an element into the stack, then the stack will be in **overflow** state. This will occur when we will use array based implementation of stack because we have to define the capacity of the array. If we want to push an element exceeding the capacity, the overflow will occur but **if we use linked list for stack implementation then how the stack overflow will occur?** In linked list we need to not to define any capacity, it dynamically allocate memory for nodes. Please help me to recognize the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that with linked list there is no need to define its capacity in terms of number of elements. But still memory is needed for the elements - and memory exhaustion can happen.
Doing a stack implementation as a list would result in slower performance (because allocation/deallocations will have to be done more often), even more convoluted if you consider that differently-sized chunks of memory have to be allocated on stack. Stack is used so extensively that any slow-down in its implementation would probably be prohibitive.
Also management of lists is harder - and you have to manage stack e.g. add more then one element at once, or 'shorten' the stack in one operation (take/forget multiple elements on it, e.g. when returning from a function call), etc. Unidirectional lists are only good at appending/removing one element at their end.
Is there any specific problem that you are going to solve? Bear in mind that stack overflow can occur not only with large data structures created on it, but also with a too deep recursion.

Comment: No its just my curiosity. But if linked list is slower  then what will be perfect to implement stack.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Linked List.As I know there are no Stack Overflows in Linked List. That's why we use that Data Structure instead of array implementations like Lists, Stacks. Implementation of Linked list is lengthy( but you can use pre-defined libraries) and high cache usage . But It's suitable for holding Data on dynamic sizes because it has the property of **dynamically allocate memory for nodes** as you mentioned above. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Rahal. That means if we use linked list then No stack overflow will occur.

Comment: @user2779650: Sure ,It does